# Редирект - замена файла с сохранением параметров

Tags: php, .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно прописать в .htaccess, если нужно создать следующий редирект:

```
http://site.com/file_name.php?id=число
```

----->

```
http://site.com/filename.php?id=число_сохранилось_такое_же_что_в_ссылке_выше
```

Comment: сами то пытались? где хоть строчка кода?

Comment: Флаг `QSA` вам поможет.

Comment: А как в такой ситуации правильно написать RewriteCond и
RewriteRule ?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^file_name.php$ filename.php [R]
```

`RewriteCond` проверяет что-бы строка параметров содержала id.

`RewriteRule` делает редирект с `file_name.php` на `filename.php`, сохраняя при этом GET параметры.

Флаг **R** говорит о том, что нужно делать внешний редирект, а не внутренний, то есть изменять url-адрес.